# Not able to insert data using MongoTemplate of Spring data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, maven, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-commons

``I am getting the following exception while instantiatingthg mongoTemplate

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/model/FieldNamingStrategy
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1962)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.(MongoTemplate.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.(MongoTemplate.java:174)
    at com.adobe.ffc.controller.MongoDBTest.createData(MongoDBTest.java:29)
    at com.adobe.ffc.controller.MongoDBTest.main(MongoDBTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.FieldNamingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 10 more

Process finished with exit code 1
the error is coming from line 1 in the following code :

```
 MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo(),"database");

        User user = new User();
        user.setId("200");
        user.setFullName("Mongo Template");
        user.setStatus("A");
        user.setAge("29");

        mongoOps.insert(user);
```

The pom configration are as follows:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you share your `User` class?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mixing Spring Data Release Trains with one another.

`spring-data-mongodb 1.4` is part of Release Train [Codd](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Codd) that requies to have `spring-data-commons 1.7`, while `spring-data-commons 1.5` which you're currently using was part of the [Arora](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Arora) release.

So either downgrade to `spring-data-mongodb 1.2` or upgrade to `spring-data-commons 1.7`. Maybe also have a look at your dependencies and check for potential conflicts.

Sidenote: you can checout the [spring data wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki) pages to see which versions have been part of a particular release.